# Select between 2 columns using 1 value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Currently I have this table called `tbl_yeast`

and in my table, i have these columns.

`id, name, low, high`

sample record would be

```
id   |   name   |   low   |    high    
1    |    ABC   |     1   |    5      
2    |    AB    |     1   |    4
3    |    C     |     2   |    4     
4    |    CD    |     6   |    10
5    |    CE    |     7   |    9
6    |    CX    |     11  |    15
```

What I want to do is:

If I have this value of `3` and select based on my `low` and `high` column the output would be :

```
id   |   name   |   low   |    high    
1    |    ABC   |     1   |    5      
2    |    AB    |     1   |    4
3    |    C     |     2   |    4
```

As you notice `3` is between in ranges of `low` and `high` column values.

And If I have this value of `8` the output would be :

```
id   |   name   |   low   |    high    
4    |    CD    |     6   |    10
5    |    CE    |     7   |    9
```

As you notice `8` is between in ranges of `low` and `high` column values.

Objective: just want to get all records that is between in these 2 columns `(low & high)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `BETWEEN` keyword here.

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_yeast` WHERE 8 BETWEEN `low` AND `high`;
```